# Inline-block buttons with large border goes two pixels down

Tags: css

I have two "inline-block" buttons, see the image below:

[image: Normal Buttons]

But, if you click, you will see the other button two pixels down.

[image]

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/caio/EUjeY/.

```
.button {
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.button:hover {
    background: #e7e7e7;
}

.button:active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 7px 10px 5px;
}
```

Can you help me to prevent this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add this to your .button class:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/uW7Sa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just give `.button` the css property `float: left` and both buttons will remain at the same location.  This is because `float: left` removes the button from the flow of the document, so aside from the containing div, it isn't affected by other, inline elements:

```
.button {
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EUjeY/3/)

I would provide more code because I'm using a float here, but I don't know what the rest of your document looks like, so I can't compensate.

Comment: I change the padding because I remove the border-bottom.

Comment: @CaioTarifa Well, that's what's causing your problem.  Did you not see the demo?  It still works.  What's wrong with this answer?

Comment: The button can't change your height when active.

Comment: @CaioTarifa That doesn't make any sense, it doesn't do that.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: See your example, the button gets smaller when it's pressed, because you used the same value for the padding. That can't happen.

Comment: @CaioTarifa That doesn't happen.  The padding doesn't change, and the height doesn't change.  The only difference is the lack of a shadow underneath the button.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome. What I mean I need increase the padding because it's necessary to compensate the size of the border-bottom that I removed. (http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/7901/btnsize.png)